# Angular 5 Http Post Not working

Tags: angular, angular5

I am invoking a POST API using Angular 5 Service

**Service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpResponse } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { IScheduleAPI } from '../interfaces/ischeduleAPI';
// import { Ischedule } from '../interfaces/ischedule';

@Injectable()
export class SchedulesService {
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:57863/api/Audit/';
  ScheduleDetail: IScheduleAPI[] = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  GetScheduleAPI(params, httpOptions) {
   return this.http.post<IScheduleAPI[]>(this.apiURL, params, httpOptions)
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server Error');
  }
}
```

I am calling this service in my Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IScheduleAPI } from '../interfaces/ischeduleAPI';
import { SchedulesService } from '../services/schedules.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedules',
  templateUrl: './schedules.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedules.component.css']
})
export class SchedulesComponent implements OnInit {
  Schedule: IScheduleAPI[];
  message: string;

  constructor(private sch: SchedulesService, private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const params = [{
      'ActionMethod': 'GetSchedule',
      'StaffCode': 'NA',
      'Password': 'NA'
    }];
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    this.sch.GetScheduleAPI(params, httpOptions).subscribe(data => this.Schedule = data,
      error => this.message = error);
  }
}
```

Now Problems

**1.]** It show error that Expected 0 type arguments but got 1 in line

```
return this.http.post<IScheduleAPI[]>(this.apiURL, params, httpOptions)
```

Its inside service file , this is the markup I am using from other service file where it is working fine .

After Removing IScheduleAPI[] it stops showing error but does not hit API than , instead show error

[image]

I am using Angular 5

Comment: You are mixing both old Http and new HttpClient modules

Comment: `Http` is deprecated use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: Just replace `constructor(private http: Http) { }` with `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`. It looks like you've already got the imports right

Comment: @David , it compile with the HttpClient and hitting the api but it does not wait for api to return result , executing other statement before result return

Comment: @Jack : which code is executed before the return? You do know that http requests are asynchronous right?

Comment: @David this service call is in ngOnInit , See my code . Its result should be return to ngOnInit , How can I make it synchronize ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  There is nothing after the call to `GetScheduleAPI` in `ngOnInit` in your code. If you want to add something right after the call, but to be executed only when the http request has returned, you can convert your code to use promises and await.async.

Comment: can you try with httpclient ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you are using the new `HttpClient` everywhere, but in the constructor.

All you need to do is to  replace

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }
```

with

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

in both `SchedulesService` and `SchedulesComponent`